# Converting API JSON result into type fails

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-core

We have some JSON which is returned like the following:

```
[
   {
       "id" : "120421421",
       "activityId" : "2049192",
       ...
   },
   {
       "id" : "24442141",
       "activityId" : "2141245",
       ...
   },
]
```

I see this question has been asked before, but not sure the answers explain the exact scenario here.
-- Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

The issue seems to be that the data is an array of results instead of just a type of class.

We call our API with a generic-based API call.

```
   result.Data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
   result.Json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The parsing of the result into the type passed in is what fails. We have a couple of classes set up to handle the results.

```
        public abstract class AvailabilityResult
        {
            public List<AvailabilityEntry> ResultList;
        }

        public abstract class AvailabilityEntry
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string activityId { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: deserialize as a collection.

Comment: @Nkosi can i do that just in the abstract class as not to affect other usages of the apiclient class which handles the response to result.data?

Comment: yes. The caller is where you need to make the array call.

Comment: I was able to get this working by changing the class definitions instead. See answer below, is there any issue with that approach? It saves having to change the api caller which is used for multiple other api'

Comment: You should be able to remove the `ResultList` property as the class itself represents the array

Answer (score 0):

```
        [JsonArrayAttribute]
        public class AvailabilityResult : List<AvailabilityEntry>
        {
            public List<AvailabilityEntry> ResultList;
        }

        public abstract class AvailabilityEntry
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string activityId { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to remove the `ResultList` property as the class itself represents the array